# How to understand "a large, slimy something suspended in green liquid"?

Tags: sentence-structure

> He tried not to look at a large, slimy something suspended in green liquid on a shelf behind Snape's desk.

I'm not sure how to parse the original sentence correctly. To me, it will be easier to understand if it's written as: *He tried not to look at **something large, slimy** suspended in green liquid on a shelf behind Snape's desk.*

What's the correct way to understand it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word **something** can be used colloquially like a noun

> It was a large, slimy something suspended in green liquid.

where it has the meaning "difficult to identify thing".

Compare also

> It was a large, slimy something-or-other suspended in green liquid.

It means the speaker can't say just what it was because the speaker doesn't really know what it was.  The speaker has no word for what it was.

P.S. The adjective can be placed before it because it is ***a*** something, that is, it is being recast as a noun.

P.P.S. The usual context for this use is *trying* to describe something that is difficult to describe to someone who is not there (or who was not there) to see or perceive it for themselves, so there's usually a descriptor of some kind placed before it.   *a mysterious something....a vague something...a little something...a nameless something...an unknown something...a certain something...a subtle something...a slimy something*

Comment: Usually, I just see when an adjective modifies 'something', it has to be placed after it, as in something wrong, not wrong something. It seems that in colloquial speech adjectives can be placed before it, as in 'large something' vs 'something large'.

Comment: Please see the P.S.

Comment: Can we say colloquially: *It is a something I don't know* without any adjectives modifying 'something'?

Comment: Please see the P.P.S. :)